# List of functions calling a specific function

Tags: python

How to get the list of functions calling a specific function in a python program.

For example, if the code is like:

```
def myFunc():
  pass

def a():
  myFunc()

def b():
  myFunc()
```

Then the functions calling `myFunc` will be `a` and `b`.

What would be the best way if there are large number of functions in the program.

Thank you.

Comment: `[a, b]` as in ?

Comment: @hansolo As in both `a` and `b` include calls of `myFunc` in their body

Comment: inspect module should be able to do that. Not trivial.

Comment: This might be a dupe, and it's a odd thing to *want* to do, but also a valid question IMO

Comment: Why do you want to get this information? What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre can give some more information on how to use inspect  module for this

Comment: use locals() to print the defined methods

Comment: I don't recommend this route, but `a.__code__.co_names` returns `('myFunc',)`

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/579105-how-a-python-function-can-find-the-name-of-its-cal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that parses the source code of a module and displays the name of each function/method that refers to a particular variable.

```
import sys
import inspect
import ast

class NameWatcher(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target
        self.current_path = []
        self.results = []
    def visit_FunctionOrClassDef(self, node):
        self.current_path.append(node.name)
        self.generic_visit(node)
        self.current_path.pop()
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node): 
        self.visit_FunctionOrClassDef(node)
    def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
        self.visit_FunctionOrClassDef(node)
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if node.id == self.target:
            self.results.append(".".join(self.current_path))

def get_name_locations(node, name):
    watcher = NameWatcher(name)
    watcher.visit(node)
    return watcher.results

class Dog:
    def bark(self):
        myFunc()

def a():
  myFunc()

def b():
  myFunc()

def myFunc():
  pass

current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
source = inspect.getsource(current_module)
ast_node = ast.parse(source)
print(get_name_locations(ast_node, "myFunc"))
```

Result:

```
['Dog.bark', 'a', 'b']
```

Caveats:

- this will not work on modules that do not have Python source code. For example the built-in `math` module.
- this will locate instances of the name, including ones that are never executed. For example `def c(): if False: myFunc()`
- this will locate instances of the name, including ones that aren't actually called. For example `def d(): return myFunc`
- this will not locate instances where myFunc is called without directly using its name. For example `def e(): globals()["myFunc"]()`

Answer (score 0):

By using the suggestion by [@Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6260170/chris-rands) I came up with this solution:

```
l = []
functions = [obj for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__])
                     if inspect.isfunction(obj)]
for i in functions:
    if "myFunc" in i.__code__.co_names:
        l.append(i.__name__)
```

l contains `a` and `b`

[@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953482/kevin) has given a even better solution.